# Zig Zag Stripes com 3 ou 4 cores - CSS3

Tags: html, css3

Olá,

Estou tentando fazer um stripe em zig-zag no css3 com 4 cores, seriam cinza, branco, rosa e branco novamente. Entretando só estou conseguindo fazer com duas cores.

```css
.zig {
  background:
    linear-gradient(135deg,
      pink 25%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 25.1%),
    linear-gradient(225deg,
      pink 25%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 25.1%),
    linear-gradient(315deg,
      pink 25%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 25.1%),
    linear-gradient(45deg,
      pink 25%,
      rgba(0,0,0,0) 25.1%),
    #ffffff;
  background-size: 40px 40px;
  background-position: -20px 0, -20px 0, 0 0, 0 0;
  width: 240px;
 height: 240px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="zig"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Olha fiz esse modelo, ele é mais simples de entender que o outro, mas usa mais gradientes para fazer... A ideia é que vc tenha apenas dois ângulos, `45deg` e `-45deg`, e desse forma vc vai "crescendo" os gradientes um por traz do outro.

Veja esse imagem para entender melhor pq tantos gradientes, e como eles se posicionam. Fiz a imagem de forma meio tosca, mas é só pra passar a ideia.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com essa ideie eu cheguei nesse "menor `pattern`", que é a fração de repetição que vamos usar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código aplicando o `pattern` *zigzag* de gradientes. ***Para diminuir a espessura das linhas de forma prática use o `background-size`.***

```css
.zig {
 background:
  linear-gradient(45deg, #ddd 15%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15.1%),
  linear-gradient(-45deg, #ddd 15%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 15.1%),
  linear-gradient(-45deg, #fff 30%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 30.1%),
  linear-gradient(45deg, #fff 30%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 30.1%),
  linear-gradient(-45deg, pink 45%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 45.1%),
  linear-gradient(45deg, pink 45%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 45.1%),
  linear-gradient(-45deg, #fff 60%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 60.1%),
  linear-gradient(45deg, #fff 60%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 60.1%),
  linear-gradient(-45deg, #ddd 75%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75.1%),
  linear-gradient(45deg, #ddd 75%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 75.1%),
  linear-gradient(-45deg, #fff 100%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100.1%),
  linear-gradient(45deg, #fff 100%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100.1%);
 background-size: 54px 80px;
 width: 380px;
 height: 460px;
 margin: 20px;
 border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="zig"></div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado era bem isso mesmo, só mais uma pergunta. E se eu quisesse editar a espessura da linha?

Comment: Ja consegui alterando a propriedade height e background-size

Comment: @BrunoFolle eu ia te sugerir isso mesmo, acho que eh a forma mais pratica para esse caso! []'s